# Recursive touch to fix syncing between computers

Tags: bash, command-line, synchronization, dropbox

I'm looking for a way from the command-line to touch every file in a directory (and subdirectories) due to a mistake of mine a synced repo of mine has gotten a bit out of step on  my development machines.

I've now through some unpleasant voodoo managed to get it back into a clean state on one machine, before I do the next sync, I want to prioritise everything time wise on this machine.

Is there an easy way to touch all the files?

Or am I better doing a manual sync of the directory?

(I'm using dropbox for syncing for reference)

Answer (score 15):

You could use `find` along with `xargs` to touch every file in the current or specified directory or below:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 touch
```

for the current directory. For a specified directory:

```
find /path/to/dir -print0 | xargs -0 touch
```

The `-print0` option to `find` along with the `-0` option to `xargs` make the command robust to file names with spaces by making the delimeter a NULL.

Edit:

As Jeremy J Starchar says in a comment, the above is only suitable if your `find` and `xargs` are a part of the GNU toolchain. If you are on a system withour GNU tools you could use:

```
find . -exec touch {} \;
```

Edit by **dcgregorya**:

Having to do this against a very large data set I've found this command to be (much) faster.

```
find ./ -type d -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 bash -c "touch {}/*"
```

Limits find to finding folders then executes touch against folder /*.

Comment: Or you can just use the `-execdir` action: `find . -execdir touch '{}' \;`

Comment: One should note that find's `-print0` and xarg's `-0` are GNU extensions and may not be present on non-GNU tool chains.  `find . -exec touch {};` is slower more compatible when needed.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a solution to my immediate problem of touching all files, whether it works with dropbox will have to be seen.

In the root of the directory in question

```
find . -print -exec touch {} \;
```

(print is extraneous but it can be helpful for feedback)